# how to use crud operations with devextreme

Tags: grid, devexpress, crud, devextreme

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var gridOptions = {
            color: 'LightSkyBlue',
            dataSource: gridData,
            paging: { pageSize: 15 },
            height: "90%",
            selection: { mode: "single" },
            editing: {
                mode: "form",
                editEnabled: true,
                insertEnabled: true,
                removeEnabled: true
            },
            filterRow: { visible: false },
            columnChooser: { enabled: true },
            columnAutoWidth: true,
            searchPanel: { visible: true },
            groupPanel: { visible: true },
            allowColumnReordering: true,
            allowColumnResizing: true,
            rowAlternationEnabled: false,
            rowClick: function (data) {
            },
            selectionChanged: function (selectedItems) {
            },
            @*columns: [
                @foreach(var item in Model.Columns){
                    <text>
                        { dataField: "@item.FieldName", caption: "@item.Caption" },
                    </text>
                }
            ]*@
        };
```

Comment: Please, describe your problem in the question body rather than post only the code.

Answer (score 2):

**Source:** [How to implement CRUD operations with a DataSource](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4816)

> To implement CRUD operations with a DataSource that obtains data from
> a remote Rest service. The DataSource object does not implement CRUD
> operations out-of-the-box. We can do this using jQuery.ajax. It is
> also necessary to call the DataSource.load method to "inform" your
> widget that it is necessary to reload its content.

example code snippet to add item to data source using a view:

```
Application1.addView = function (params) {
    var viewModel = {
        categoryName: ko.observable(),
        btnSaveClick: function (e) {
            var category = {
                CategoryID: 0,
                CategoryName: viewModel.categoryName()
            }
            Application1.db.insert(category).done(function (data) {
                app.back();
            });
        }
    };
    return viewModel;
};
```

**References:**
[How to implement CRUD operations with a DataSource](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E4816.aspx)
[dxDataGrid - How to implement a custom store with CRUD operations (SQLite)](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/T218257.aspx)

Hope this help you to move forward. :)